# Why is a <<create>> message asynchronous in UML sequence diagrams?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

As far I as I could tell, the proper way to show an object creation in a sequence diagram is with an asynchronous arrow, e.g.,

[image]

However, in Java (and other OO languages I have used), as far as I know, a `new()` operation is blocking.

I noticed that some references (Craig Larman) use a hybrid message (dotted line with filled arrow), e.g.,

[image]

Especially when a constructor is involved, it's important that a `create` be a *synchronous* call. That is, it will return when the constructor is finished. According to my understanding of asynchronous messages in UML, the `:A` object would not wait for the constructor of `:B` to finish.

My students often ask this question, and I suspect there is some history behind this. I'm curious why there is this seeming inconsistency.

Comment: Do they also ask about UML inheritance letting an object change type including having base classes added with state changes?    Personally I have never found UML useful other than giving me a set of shapes I can draw with…….   And most programmer has no concept of the meaning of most UML symbols, so UML is little more than a set of class diagrams on most projects.

Comment: UML predates Java/C# being in common use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each UML message in an interaction diagram has a unique `MessageSort`, which are mutually exclusive (section 17.4.2):

> synchCall
>  
>       asynchCall
>  
>       asynchSignal
>  
>       createMessage
>  
>       deleteMessage
>  
>       reply

The graphical notation of the message is defined depending on `MessageSort` (section 17.4.4.1):

> - An asynchronous Message (messageSort equals asynchCall or asynchSignal) has an open arrow head.
> - A synchronous Message (messageSort equals synchCall) has a filled arrow head.
> - A reply Message (messageSort equals reply) has a dashed line with either an open or filled arrow head.
> - An object creation Message (messageSort equals createMessage) has a dashed line with an open arrow head.
> - An object deletion Message (messageSort equals deleteMessage) must end in a
> - ...

So, this [graphical representation](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html#create) is a convention and you shall not be mislead to  derive a semantic from it !  If you see a `« create »` message with an open arrow head, it's not because it would be asynchronous, but simply because that's the way UML decided to represent the creation.

I agree that it's ambiguous: it looks like a reply message, and it's not consistent with the meaning given to arrow heads. Maybe some improvement to suggest to the UML standard committee ? The market didn't wait: there are already [some tools](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_8.5.1/com.ibm.xtools.sequence.doc/topics/cmsg_v.html) that use normal synchronous message arrows.

Comment: UML has so many versions now I just laugh when people call it a standard.

Comment: This explains why I got an unexplained downvote on my question (i.e., shame on you for deriving a semantic from the symbols).

Comment: @candied_orange I was talking about [this UML 2.5.1 specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/) approved by OMG who has authority on it.  I admit calling it abusively a standard, since the official standard is [ISO 19505](https://www.iso.org/standard/32624.html), which corresponds to UML 2.4.1.  The differences are minor: 198 CHF (the cost of the older ISO standard compared to the free up-to-date OMG specification) ;-)

Comment: Also worth to mention that UML is much more unified than OOSE, Booch and OMT were, before their authors decided to join forces.

Comment: Unfortunately I've been subjected to so many misused undefined indecipherable UML dodads that I don't trust that I know what I'm looking at until I beat it out of some one. I'm with the students. "Huh?"

Comment: @candied_orange I'm with the students: "OMG!" :)